# How to set value in bean using use c:set with jsf?

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee

I have another problem to solve. I have a code on my xhtml page:

```
<t:dataList id="myDataList" value="#{myBean.myList}" var="element" first="0" `rows="10" dir="LTR" frame="hsides" rules="all">`
<c:set target="#{myBean}" property="fid" value="#{element[0]}"/>
...
</t:dataList>
```

The problem is that value of 'fid' in a bean is null when I`m checking it. When I wrote:

```
<c:set target="#{myBean}" property="fid" value="8"/>
```

everything works fine and value is set to '8'. How should i fix this? Thanks for replies.

Answer (score 0):

JSTL tags runs during view build time. JSF tags runs during view render time. You can visualize it as follows: JSTL runs from top to bottom first when the JSF component tree is to be populated, then hands over the component tree to JSF and finally JSF runs from top to bottom to render the HTML.

The `element[0]` is not there when JSTL is creating the view. It's only there when JSF is rendering the HTML. However, `8` is hardcoded and it is always there.

There are several ways to achieve it the proper way, but since the functional requirement is unclear, I can't suggest a proper approach. Maybe you need `f:setPropetyActionListener`. Maybe you need `DataModel#getRowData()` or `UIData#getRowData()`. Or maybe you don't need it at all.

Comment: Thanks for explaining me this. Fortunately I have already found another solution of my problem where i don`t need to use this code. Regards for you!